# File Watcher in PhpStorm compiles too quick

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm, file-watcher

How can I improve the File Watcher to compile a SCSS to CSS after I press <kbd>Cmd + S</kbd> (for save)?

The problem is that the File Watcher compiled the files too quick so sometimes results in an error, because I'm still writing the function or CSS tags. That causes a lots of trouble and takes so much time and to be honest, disturbs the workflow.

Comment: Show your File Watcher settings (expand all areas). There will be an option that will prevent auto-executing unless saved.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you, that worked. But now sometimes an error occurs https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8av40rx2txn5qe/Screenshot%202018-05-11%2009.16.34.png?dl=0 . do you know why or what this is?

Comment: How long it takes to compile it? I see you are most likely using Ruby-powered compiler. Do you want to try [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#command-line-interface) (`npm install node-sass -g`).. or [Dart powered one](http://sass-lang.com/dart-sass)? They are noticeable faster. Arguments are a bit different though .. but that just a matter of checking the right one with `--help` parameter, right?

Comment: No I've never tried, I thought there would be simply a method to make the time out longer so we can change it to 2 seconds or something similar. Currently the compiler takes 1 to 2 seconds to compile, depends on how large the file is.

Comment: 1-2 seconds should not be a problem at all ... Maybe lena can give you better suggestion/answer -- she is from WebStorm team.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In file watcher settings, **Advanced options**, try clearing **Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher** checkbox:

[image]

the watcher will be triggered on explicit `CMD + S`/moving focus from the IDE only

Comment: That helped, thank you! But do you get sometimes an error (yellow) below the code editor that says "File Watcher took too long and was canceld because of a timeout" (similiar like that, I dont know the exact error phrase)?

Comment: Currently autoupload works this way: after explicit save action IDE tries to wait till file watcher's tasks finish. It's done to upload transpiled files together with changed (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16410). If it takes more than time limit (5 seconds), IDE stops waiting and just uploads all changed files, printing that 'Automatic upload: check for related changes from File Watchers took too much time and was cancelled.' message.

Comment: And there is no way to rise the limit to about 6 or 8 seconds? I guess the compiler is done with his task because after the upload (shortly after the message pops in) the changed content is visible online.

Comment: this limit is not configurable afaik:( You can file a feature request to [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) on this